# how connect to azure blob storage using java script

Tags: javascript

i am very new to java script.i am writing an azure logic app in java script and trying to store all data in blob.
Is there any one tried to connect to azure blob storage using java script.please guide

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you want to use javascript in logic app for blob operation. Its pretty easy with logic app connector. Have a look at this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage